# Reset AWS autoscaling warm pool instances during deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, aws-auto-scaling

I have a rails app running on an AWS autoscaling group with a warm pool of 2 stopped instances. When I deploy my code, I deploy code on the running instances, then I create a new ami that will be used for the future instances that will scale-out.
My problem is: the code is never deployed on the warm pool instances, because I cannot deploy on stopped instances (I think)... How could I solve this issue?

I consider using lambda function to terminate warm pool instances when a deployment occurs.